# Checkstyle: enforce empty line after close curly / before return

Tags: java, checkstyle

Looking for a Checkstyle rule to enforce empty lines in some situations:

**Empty Line After Close Curly**

```java
if (something)
{
    // not important
}
doSomethingElse();
```

**Empty Line Before Return**

```java
final var result = doSomething();
return result;
```

Comment: IIRC there’s nothing for this by default; perhaps someone has written one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a simple `RegexpMultiline` module which should work for now thought it may not catch all cases:

```xml
<!-- Enforces blank lines after block-closing curly braces (with exceptions). -->
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="format" value="}\n(?![ \t]*(else|case|catch|finally|[})]|\*)|$)"/>
</module>
```